# What do 切入点 and 突破口 mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Today I hear the news on radio that the pollution work in Hebei, China deteriortates when some public officers are involved in the scandal of discharging polluted water. Then an official of the local environmental authority said when interviewed by media that 我们将以XXX为切入点，以治污XX为突破口(sorry, some words are beyond my understanding), I think my script is nearly perfect or accurate, but what they mean really I like to hear what you say.

Comment: 切入点jukuu 78 samples Line Dictionary 44 examples
突破口jukuu 61 samples Line Dictionary 34 examples

Comment: 切入点 is the right point from which you can start to work, while 突破口 is the key point for you to break through, be successful

Answer (score 1):

切入点: starting point, point of view

突破口: point of breakthrough

For example:

我们将以工业排放为切入点, 以污染源头为突破口.

(We will take industrial emission as our starting point, the source of pollution as breakthrough.)

爆米花理论似乎是一个无聊的切入点.

The theory of popcorn might seem a boring view.

Answer (score 0):

Both mean *the point to start dealing with something*. Usually it is for the point most important or effective to start working with in order to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well... without specifying the whole phrase, I suppose you mean "we proceed with the front of..." or "we approach the problem first with..."

我們以減少工業排放為治污的突破口。

We approach the problem of pollution by reducing industrial carbon emission.

Answer (score 0):

Both 切入点 (cut-in point) and 突破口 (breakthrough opening) are common military term.

- 切入点- treat a problem as an enemy. To attack an enemy frontally, it is best to choose a weak point to cut into the enemy line and defeat them from within.

Meaning: "**A cut-in point to get to the core of the problem and deal with it**"

- 突破口- treat a problem as an enemy. If the enemy has a well formed defensive line, you have to find an opening to breakthrough it; If you are surrounded by the enemy, you also have to find an opening to breakthrough in order to save the situation.

Meaning: 1. "**A breakthrough opening to get to the core of the problem and deal with it**" 2. "**A breakthrough opening to get out of the crisis**"

> 我们将以[XXX]为切入点，以治污XX为突破口

"我们将以[減少工業排放]为切入点，以治污[反腐]为突破口"

"We will use 'reduce industrial emissions' as the cut-in (starting) point; and use 'combat and eradicate corruption' as the breakthrough opening (to deal with the pollution problem)." -- *and yes, pollution is our enemy and corruption is one of the causes*"